# How to resolve the question of typescript generic function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

```
class Context {}

declare function call<C>( method: ( value: unknown, context: C ) => unknown ): any;

declare function fn1<T>( value: T, context: Context  ): Promise<T>;
declare function fn2( value: unknown, context: Context ): unknown;

call( fn1 );
call( fn2 );
```

I have code above, and you can also view it in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7ALgUwB7OgbwL4FgAoIgE1VDACdVoAzAV0WGQEslpgwQQAeWAPgAU0ALapkAC3gkAXNGEA3LvVRzGAa0TwA7ogA0HJGkxzY0AJTQAvP2gatui3LCIAngG4ipcuGp1GzGyIdIgAjDwAKkLQSiAqchEGwEYYyKYpmNBO0AAKlPAiLBCokfyehGQUfgxMrOy0iABMisqqdoiaOvqGKKnpvZnmah0OiOVEnNzCDaEW5ZMg001zQA).

`call( fn1 )` triggered error message:

```
Argument of type '<T>(value: T, context: Context) => Promise<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, context: unknown) => unknown'.
  Types of parameters 'context' and 'context' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Context'.(2345)
```

But `call( fn2 )` works well.

Is it because `fn1` is a generic function and why?

Comment: Probably the general limitation is outlined in [ms/TS#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), although the particular situation is not something I've found in GitHub yet.  TypeScript's inference algorithm is heuristic in nature and sometimes fails to find matching candidates; you can fix it by manually instantiating one of the generics it fails to infer, either by `call<Context>(fn1);` or in TS4.7+ by `call(fn1<unknown>);`, shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAyQPm).

Comment: It works if you write `call<Context>(fn1)`. For some reason - it might as well be a bug - the type parameter `C` is inferred to `unknown`.

Comment: It might be interesting to file an issue in GitHub using [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp9LzW) as a minimal example, asking why the inference fails.  I assume there's already an existing issue asked but I haven't found it yet (and probably won't tonight ).